# Efficent algorithm for find the subset of a set of 8 bit integers, whose elements do not contain each other which has the maximum number of elements

Tags: algorithms, extremal-combinatorics

I want to find a subset of the set of all 8 bit unsigned integers, this subset contains elements that do not contain another (x contains y if x & y == x). The subset should have the maximum number of elements. Beside brute forcing, I couldn't think of a way to efficiently generate this set.

Comment: $\binom 84=70$, the number of 8-bit integers with four 1s and four 0s.

Comment: Your containment relation is a partial order, and you are looking for a [maximum antichain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain#Computational_complexity) of this partial order. I don't know what you mean by brute forcing here, but this operation can be done polynomial time.

Comment: @TonyK thanks for pointers, I will check them out. By brute forcing, I mean just list out all the subsets and check if they satisfy the conditions (which takes a long long time).

Comment: @DanielMathias can you elaborate why that is the answer?

Comment: There are $2^{256}$ such subsets, which completely rules out your proposed brute force approach.

Comment: @TonyK yeah, that’s why i’m looking for another approach

Comment: *Is* the subset that I suggested the solution? I made no such claim. I leave it to you to consider whether a larger subset can satisfy the stated conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sperner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem): an antichain of subsets of a set of $n$ elements has cardinality at most $${n \choose \lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$$
In this case $n=8$, and the antichain consists of all $8$-bit integers with $4$ ones.